# Want to modify Path / Classpath variables of remote linux server using putty

Tags: linux

I want to modify my path and classpath of remote linux server using putty. Currently on remote server class Path is set as following : `:/home/rpms/jdk1.5.0_15/lib:/home/rpms/apache-tomcat-5.5.17/common/lib:/home/rpms/apache-tomcat-5.5.17/common/lib/servlet-api.jar`.
Now I want to modify it as following :
`:/home/rpms.jdk1.8.0_18/lib:/home/rpms/apache-tomcat-8.x.y/lib:` etc. So Here I just want to update jdk5 with jdk8 and apache-tomcate-5.x.y/common with apache-tomcat-8.x.y on my path.

Kindly guide me out in it. Here path is shown for just reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changing the classpath won't make Java 8 out of a Java 5 VM. You need to install a full Java 8 JDK and then start Tomcat with a correct path to it in the variable `JAVA_HOME`. Put the variable into the file `/home/rpms/apache-tomcat-8.x.y/bin/setenv.sh`

The correct value for `JAVA_HOME` is the folder which contains `bin/` and `jre/`. I.e. `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version` must work and print the version number that you expect.